# Convert Pkcs11X509Certificate to X509Certificate2 to use as ssl client cert

Tags: ssl, client-certificates, pkcs11interop, hardware-security-module

I am quite new to this... I have safenet luna hsm storing certs. I need to retrieve cert
and use it as client cert in an ssl session.
I am trying to use Pkcs11Interop (and also Pkcs11X509Store) without success. I cant get the X509Certificate2 with the private key.
here is what I have so far :
with Pkcs11X509Store:

```
using (var store = new Pkcs11X509Store(@"c:\program files\Safenet\Lunaclient\cryptoki.dll", new ConstPinProvider(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["pin"])))
        {
            Pkcs11X509Certificate cert = store.Slots[0].Token.Certificates.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Info.ParsedCertificate.SerialNumber.ToLower() == ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["certsn"].ToLower());
            //RSA rsaPrivateKey = cert.GetRSAPrivateKey();
            X509Certificate2 x509cert = cert.Info.ParsedCertificate;
            // here cert.HasPrivateKeyObject is true but x509cert.HasPrivateKey is false
        }
```

so x509cert is not working as valid cert for ssl...

with Pkcs11Interop :

```
using (IPkcs11Library pkcs11Library = Settings.Factories.Pkcs11LibraryFactory.LoadPkcs11Library(Settings.Factories, Settings.Pkcs11LibraryPath, Settings.AppType))
            {
                ISlot slot = Helpers.GetUsableSlot(pkcs11Library);
                using (ISession session = slot.OpenSession(SessionType.ReadOnly))
                {
                    session.Login(CKU.CKU_USER, Settings.NormalUserPin);
                    List<IObjectAttribute> objectAttributes = new List<IObjectAttribute>();
                    objectAttributes.Add(session.Factories.ObjectAttributeFactory.Create(CKA.CKA_CLASS, CKO.CKO_CERTIFICATE));
                    session.FindObjectsInit(objectAttributes);
                    X509Certificate2 x509cert  = new X509Certificate2();
                    List<IObjectHandle> foundObjects = session.FindAllObjects(objectAttributes);
                    string cka_id = "";
                    foreach (IObjectHandle foundObjectHandle in foundObjects)
                    {
                        List<IObjectAttribute> certAttributes = session.GetAttributeValue(foundObjectHandle, new List<CKA>() { CKA.CKA_VALUE, CKA.CKA_ID });
                        X509Certificate2 x509Cert2 = new X509Certificate2(certAttributes[0].GetValueAsByteArray());
                        if (x509Cert2.SerialNumber.ToLower() == ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["certsn"].ToLower())
                        {
                            cka_id = certAttributes[1].GetValueAsString();
                            x509cert  = x509Cert2;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    objectAttributes.Clear();
                    objectAttributes.Add(session.Factories.ObjectAttributeFactory.Create(CKA.CKA_CLASS, CKO.CKO_PRIVATE_KEY));
                    foundObjects.Clear();
                    foundObjects = session.FindAllObjects(objectAttributes);
                    foreach (IObjectHandle foundObjectHandle in foundObjects)
                    {
                        List<IObjectAttribute> keyAttributes = session.GetAttributeValue(foundObjectHandle, new List<CKA>() { CKA.CKA_VALUE, CKA.CKA_ID });
                        if (cka_id == keyAttributes[1].GetValueAsString())
                        {
                            //how to assign private key to x509cert  ?
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    session.FindObjectsFinal();
```

Is there a way to get a X509Certificate2 which can be used later as ssl client cert ?

Thanks in advance for any help.

/JS

Comment: If you just want to get the certificate out, you can use the Luna command line utilities.

Answer (score 0):

Instances of `X509Certificate2` classes returned by `Pkcs11Interop.Store` library cannot be used in SSL connections. That's a known limitation caused by [limited extensibility of `X509Certificate2` class](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/22437). If you want to use `X509Certificate2` object with SSL connections then you need to get it from standard [X509Store](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509store?view=netframework-4.8).

Comment: Thanks for your answer Jariq, is it possible to add hsm certs with  x509store ?

Comment: @user20292184 `X509Store` class provides access to all certificates propagated into windows certificate store. Take a look at your device documentation for more details on how to propagate your device certificates into windows certificate store. Sometimes it is also referred to as CAPI, CSP, CNG, KSP etc. If you are unfamiliar with those terms then your best bet is to contact device vendor support.